# Converting columns to row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem: I have my base table that stores username, and their feedback response. In the table with each user I have 2 questions and 2 responses.

`ans1 ans2` are text columns where user can entry their comments against each question/answer pair.

Input table:

```
username    question1   question2   opt1    ans1    opt2    ans2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
user1   ques1   ques2   a   answer1 b   answer2
user2   ques1   ques2   c   answer11    d   answer21
```

I want my output (for the given input as above table)query should produce a result in below format:

```
Username    Question    Option  Comment
----------------------------------------------------
user1   ques1   a   answer1
user1   ques2   b   answer2
user2   ques1   c   answer11
user2   ques2   d   answer21
```

I tried this query to get the result but it is somehow taking all possible combinations..pls suggest..

```
SELECT Username,Question,Answers,Options
FROM 
(SELECT username,opt1,opt2,ans1,ans2,ques1,ques2  
FROM dbo.tab1) p
    UNPIVOT(Question FOR q1 IN (ques1, ques2))AS unpvt1
    UNPIVOT(Answers FOR answer1  IN (ans1, ans2))AS unpvt2
    UNPIVOT(Options FOR a  IN (opt1, opt2))AS unpvt3
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can query this without using UNPIVOT; Please check

```
select 
    distinct UserName, 
    Question1 AS Question, 
    Opt1 AS OPT, 
    Ans1 AS Comment 
From 
    tblFeedback where Question1='Quest1'
UNION ALL
select 
    distinct UserName, 
    Question2 AS Question, 
    Opt2 AS OPT, 
    Ans2 AS Comment 
From 
    tblFeedback where Question2='Quest2'
```